# Edit specific row of a table using id of that row without database operations using jquery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

Edit specific row of a table using id of that row without database operations.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <link href="styleKMF.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://prototype.xsanisty.com/calx/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://prototype.xsanisty.com/calx/jquery-calx-1.1.8.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="addRow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var currentRow = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calx').calx();
   //insert row
   $('#irow').click(function(){
       if($('#G1').val()){
           $('#list tbody').append($("#list tbody tr:last").clone());

           $('#list tbody tr:last td:first').html($('#G1').val());
           $('#list tbody tr:last td:last').html($('#H1').val());
           $('#list tbody tr:last td:last').html($('#I1').val());
           $('#list tbody tr:last td:last').html($('#J1').val());
           $('#list tbody tr:last td:last').html($('#E1').val());

       }
   });

   //Edit a specific row based on id and update it
    $("td", this).on("click", function () {
        var tds = $(this).parents("tr").find("td");
        $.each(tds, function (i, v) {
            $($("#myForm input")[i]).val($(v).text());
        });
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="calx">
            <div id="spacer"></div>
            <form name="serviceForm" >
                <label for="serviceName">Service Name:</label>
                <select name="particulars" id="G1"> 
                    <%
                    try{
                        Connection connection = DBConnectionManager.getConnection();
                        CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ CALL get_master_services(?)}");
                        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

                        callableStatement.execute();
                        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
                        while(rs.next()){
                          String id1 = rs.getString("service_desc");
                    %>
                    <option value="<%=id1 %>"><%=id1 %></option>
                    <%
                        }
                    }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                             out.println("wrong entry"+e);
                        }
                   %>
                </select><br><br>
                <label for="month">Month:</label>
                    <select name="month" id="H1">
                        <option>Select Month</option>
                        <option>January</option>
                        <option>February</option>
                        <option>March</option>
                        <option>April</option>
                        <option>May</option>
                        <option>June</option>
                        <option>July</option>
                        <option>August</option>
                        <option>September</option>
                        <option>October</option>
                        <option>November</option>
                        <option>December</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="year">Year:</label>
                    <select name="year" id="I1">
                        <option>Select Year</option>
                        <option>2014</option>
                        <option>2015</option>
                        <option>2016</option>
                        <option>2017</option>
                    </select><br><br>
                    <td>
                        <label for="details">Details:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="details" id="J1" style="width:'50px';">
                </td><br><br>   
            <tr>
                <td><label for="Tax">Tax:</label><input type="text" id="B1" value="" data-format="0,0[.]00" /></td><br><br>
                <td><label for="Tax">Cess:</label><input type="text" id="C1" value="" data-format="0,0[.]00" /></td><br><br>
                <td><label for="Tax">Interest/Penality:</label><input type="text" id="D1" value="" data-format="0,0[.]00 " /></td><br><br>
                <td><label for="Tax">Total:</label><input type="text" name="total" id="E1" value="" data-format="0,0[.]00" data-formula="($B1+$C1+$D1)" /></td><br>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="irow" value="Add" onclick="Javascript:addRow()" ></td>
                <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
            <hr>

            <table id="list" border="1" >                
                <tr>
                    <td>Service Name</td>
                    <td>Month</td>
                    <td>Year</td>
                    <td>Details</td>
                    <td>Amount</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>                    
            </table>

<!--        <tr>
                <td colspan="6" style="text-align: right">Total Price :</td>
                <td id="F1" data-format="0,0[.]00" data-formula="SUM($E1,$E5)"></td>
            </tr>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

i have done this using jquery also, but displaying only first and last column values, but not the between columns. How can i display between columns and how can i edit row after displaying values using jquery. How to fetch that specific row values on to the form?

Comment: Should i create new form for edit operation or Can we perform on the same form. Can someone help me to solve my problem please....

Comment: $('#list tbody tr:eq(index)')   using equal you can pass index of tr and get object of particular tr.  same way in td

Comment: $('#list tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').html()   . check like this

Comment: let me know it is working or not ?

Comment: Thank you soo much....  @jQuery
 It is working perfect. but tr:eq(0) must be tr:eq(1) - 
 $('#list tbody tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)').html();

Comment: WC. you can use index value as your requirement. i just post example.

Comment: ok ok.. thank you.. @jQuery. How to clear a form after click or submit..?

Comment: $('#myForm').trigger("reset"); use this  or $('#myForm')[0].reset();

Comment: if my answer is help full to you pls accept my answer and up vote also  :)

Comment: Can anyone help me in editing a specific row...? When i click on edit it should fetch specific row values on to the form and update it.

Comment: you can ask this is as separate  question .. you can correct his answers if it help you .

Comment: You are including jQuery twice in your example, once from prototype.xsanisty.com and once from code.jquery.com. You might want to include it only once, before you include the other scripts that depend on jquery.

Comment: Thank you @Lwangaman. If i remove code.jquery.com my calculation part is not working.. Is there any other way...?

Comment: it should work just the same because they are both exactly the same script... you must make sure you include the jquery script before the calx script (and it seems to me that that is the case here), if you have errors it may need some debugging but that is going off the topic here, if you need help debugging I can look over a sample with you on jsfiddle. I started to put together a sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/jj9g5x06/ but it is missing your "addRow.js" script. You can send me a PM and we work on it outside of here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [equal](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) you can pass index of tr and get object of particular tr. same way in td
see below example

```
$('#list tbody tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)').html();
```